# How can I change multithreading with multiprocessing in the code (Python)

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing, caesar-cipher

I wrote a program which implements caesar-cipher with threads and queues with python. I would like to change all the threading work with multiprocessing in my code and I have no idea how to do it. I would appreciate if you could explain where & how to start the implementation. Here is the code:

```
import threading
import Queue
import sys
import string

lock = threading.Lock()
def do_work(in_queue, out_queue, shift):
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        item = in_queue.get()
        result = caesar(item, shift)
        out_queue.put(result)
        in_queue.task_done()
        lock.release()
def caesar(plaintext, shift):
    plaintext = plaintext.upper()
    alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
    shifted_alphabet = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
    table = string.maketrans(alphabet, shifted_alphabet)
    return plaintext.translate(table)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print("Duzgun giriniz: '<filename>.py s n l'")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        s = int(sys.argv[1])
        n = int(sys.argv[2])
        l = int(sys.argv[3])

    work = Queue.Queue()
    results = Queue.Queue()
    myfile=open('metin.txt','r')
    text_data=myfile.read() # <=== here load file
    index=0

    for i in xrange(n):
        t = threading.Thread(target=do_work, args=(work, results, s))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for i in range(0, len(text_data), l):
        work.put(text_data[index:index + l])
        index += l

    work.join()

    index=0
    output_file=open("crypted"+ "_"+ str(s)+"_"+str(n)+"_"+str(l)+".txt", "w")
    for i in range(0, len(text_data), l):
        output_file.write(results.get())
        index += l
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: The lock in `do_work` is a problem. But it shouldn't be there anyway. `Queue.get` is already thread safe so you are not protecting it. Instead, all of your threads wait on that lock while 1 thread does the work. You've effectively single-threaded your multithread app.

Comment: You could replace most of your code with a `multiprocessing.Pool` pool and use its `map` method. As an additional benefit, `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` implements a thread version with the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself some code and move to the standard `multiprocessing.Pool` implementation.

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
import string
import itertools

# for non-forking systems like Windows
def worker(args):
    # args: (text, shift)
    return caesar(*args)

# for forking systems like linux
def forking_worker(args):
    # args: ((start_index, end_index), shift)
    return caesar(text_data[args[0][0]:args[0][1], args[1])

def caesar(plaintext, shift):
    plaintext = plaintext.upper()
    alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
    shifted_alphabet = alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]
    table = string.maketrans(alphabet, shifted_alphabet)
    return plaintext.translate(table)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print("Duzgun giriniz: '<filename>.py s n l'")
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        s = int(sys.argv[1])
        n = int(sys.argv[2])
        l = int(sys.argv[3])

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool() # todo: change number of cpus...
    with open('metin.txt') as myfile:
        text_data=myfile.read() # <=== here load file

    # on a forking system so only pass index, not text to child
    result = pool.map(forking_worker, 
        zip(((index, index + l)
            for index in range(0, len(text_data), l)),
            itertools.cycle([s])))

    with open("crypted"+ "_"+ str(s)+"_"+str(n)+"_"+str(l)+".txt", "w") as output_file:
        output_file.writelines(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, even though I wanted to use forks in order to implement this multiprocessing, this seems to work better. Do you have any suggestion on how to get started with learning Pool functions?

Comment: The standard docs at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html are a good start. But there are gotcha's along the way so extra googling of specific methods is a good idea. For instance, in the example i gave you, since you are on a forking operating system, you don't need to send the text to the child. I'll update using an index instead.